# D open native device on Windows/Linux

Tags: d

I'm very new to D and I have a C++ background.

I would like to try sending SCSI CDBs using D lang. Is there a class in D that allows me to open a native device in Windows similar to the [Windows CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) function? I'm looking for D stuff similar to [sg_io_hdr_t](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-Generic-HOWTO/sg_io_hdr_t.html) as well.

Any ideas that I can play with? If D cannot do this, I know I can write the C++ code and link to it from D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call the Windows `CreateFile` function directly (though you may need to use `CreateFileA` or `CreateFileW` instead because D doesn't always define the convenience names like C++ does). There's three ways:

1) Some of the operating system headers are included with the D download. `import core.sys.windows.windows;` will work for `CreateFileA` (or W, which is the wide char (unicode) version). `WriteFile` is also in there along with many other basic functions.

For Unix headers, `import core.sys.posix.unistd;` and friends can help. If you would use `#include <foo.h>` in C, try `import core.sys.posix.foo;` in D.

2) The Windows headers that come with D are really minimal. You can try downloading more complete ones from here https://github.com/AndrejMitrovic/DWinProgramming/tree/master/WindowsAPI

For other libraries, try doing a quick search here and maybe you'll find bindings too http://code.dlang.org/

3) If those fail, you can always copy/paste the function and struct definitions from C into D. For example, if you need `ReadFileEx`, you'll find it isn't in `core.sys.windows.windows`. You can call it by just adding this to your file:

```
    extern(Windows)
            BOOL ReadFileEx(HANDLE, LPVOID, DWORD, OVERLAPPED*, void*);
```

The definition which you can get from MSDN, with some of the extra macros and such removed. Instead of `WINAPI`, you write `extern(Windows)`, then most the rest of the function is the same. (Be sure to still import the core.sys.windows.windows though so you have definitions of stuff like DWORD.)

Then you can just call the function normally. You can also do `extern(C)` for Unix functions from other libraries. Be sure to use `c_long` and `c_ulong` when you see `long` and `unsigned long` in C though because they aren't necessarily the same as a `long` in D. Those types are found in `import core.stdc.config;`.

Similarly, structs can be copy/pasted as needed into D and made available, again, just translate the member types to the equivalent D, being sure to keep them in the same order. Tip: if the struct is always used just by pointer, you might get away with just passing `void*` around instead of the actual definition. You lose a bit of type safety but it often works.

Comment: Cool,that helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To add to Adam's answer:

As of DMD 2.066, you can use the function [`windowsHandleOpen`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#.File.windowsHandleOpen) to associate any Windows `HANDLE` (as obtained via `CreateFile`) with a `std.stdio.File`. This should allow you to use D's `std.stdio` with arbitrary Windows handle objects (devices, pipes, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

With Adam's help I came up with this code ([rewrite of this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-Generic-HOWTO/pexample.html)):

```
import core.sys.posix.sys.ioctl  : ioctl;
import core.stdc.errno           : errno;
import std.stdio                 : write, writef, writeln, writefln, File;
import std.xml                   : isChar;

const int SG_IO = 0x2285;
const int SG_DXFER_FROM_DEV = -3;
const uint SG_INFO_OK_MASK = 1;
const uint SG_INFO_OK = 0;
const uint INQ_LEN = 6;

struct _sg_io_hdr
{
   int interface_id; /* [i] 'S' for SCSI generic (required) */
   int dxfer_direction; /* [i] data transfer direction  */
   ubyte cmd_len; /* [i] SCSI command length ( <= 16 bytes) */
   ubyte mx_sb_len; /* [i] max length to write to sbp */
   ushort iovec_count; /* [i] 0 implies no scatter gather */
   uint dxfer_len; /* [i] byte count of data transfer */
   void * dxferp; /* [i], [*io] points to data transfer memory
                  or scatter gather list */
   ubyte * cmdp; /* [i], [*i] points to command to perform */
   ubyte * sbp; /* [i], [*o] points to sense_buffer memory */
   uint timeout; /* [i] MAX_UINT->no timeout (unit: millisec) */
   uint flags; /* [i] 0 -> default, see SG_FLAG... */
   int pack_id; /* [i->o] unused internally (normally) */
   void * usr_ptr; /* [i->o] unused internally */
   ubyte status; /* [o] scsi status */
   ubyte masked_status;/* [o] shifted, masked scsi status */
   ubyte msg_status; /* [o] messaging level data (optional) */
   ubyte sb_len_wr; /* [o] byte count actually written to sbp */
   ushort host_status; /* [o] errors from host adapter */
   ushort driver_status;/* [o] errors from software driver */
   int resid; /* [o] dxfer_len - actual_transferred */
   uint duration; /* [o] time taken by cmd (unit: millisec) */
   uint info; /* [o] auxiliary information */
} /* 64 bytes long (on i386) */

void writeBuffer(char[] buff, int length)
{
   for (int k = 0; k < buff.length; ++k)
   {
      if ((k > 0) && (0 == (k % 8)))
      {
         writeln();
      }
      // breaks output of non-chars in char range, but who cares in this code
      if (isChar(buff[k]))
      {
         write(" ", cast(char)(buff[k]), " ");
      }
      else
      {
         writef("%02x ", buff[k]);
      }
   }
}


int main()
{
   _sg_io_hdr io_hdr;

   char[INQ_LEN] cdb = 0;
   char[32] senseBuffer = 0;
   char[96] inqBuffer = 0;

   cdb[0] = 0x12;
   cdb[4] = cdb.length;

   io_hdr.interface_id      = 'S';
   io_hdr.cmd_len           = cdb.length;
   io_hdr.cmdp              = cast(ubyte*)(cdb);
   io_hdr.mx_sb_len         = senseBuffer.length;
   io_hdr.sbp               = cast(ubyte*)(senseBuffer);
   io_hdr.dxfer_len         = inqBuffer.length;
   io_hdr.dxferp            = cast(ubyte*)(inqBuffer);
   io_hdr.dxfer_direction   = SG_DXFER_FROM_DEV;
   io_hdr.timeout           = 5000;

   auto file = File("/dev/sdb", "rb");
   int res = ioctl(file.fileno(), SG_IO, &io_hdr);
   file.close();

   if (res < 0)
   {
      writeln("ERROR: inquiry SG_IO ioctl error ", errno);
   }
   if ((io_hdr.info & SG_INFO_OK_MASK) != SG_INFO_OK)
   {
      writeln("ERROR: io_hdr.info is not OK");
   }

   writefln("INQUIRY duration=%u millisecs, resid=%d\n",
      io_hdr.duration, io_hdr.resid);

   writeln("INQUIRY inquiry buffer: ");
   writeBuffer(inqBuffer, inqBuffer.length);
   writeln("\n");
   return 0;
}
```